# Does it hurt for domain A to link to a NOINDEX page at domain B?

Tags: pagerank, noindex

Two pages A and B are at two different domains:

Page A links to page B. After a while, I decided to mark page B NOINDEX using meta robots "noindex, follow".

Do I have to add `rel=nofollow` to page A or just leave it as it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it hurt for domain A to link to a NOINDEX page at domain B?

It would not "hurt" domain A.

> Do I have to add `rel=nofollow` to page A or just leave it as it is?

You do not need to add `rel=nofollow`. Since the page you are linking to is already `noindex`, adding `rel=nofollow` is unnecessary.

It sounds like you have control of both domain A and domain B. If, however, domain B was under the control of some popular third party. Then if what you are asking was true then the "third party" could inflict SEO damage on the sites that are linking to it by simply making the page `noindex`. This would not make sense and is never going to happen.